# Declare array structure for function (...args)

Tags: typescript

Is there a way specify that function `foo` can accept unlimited number of arguments as an array of 3 numbers, but last parameter must be a number?

```
function foo(...args:number[]|number[][])
{
  const first = args[0] as [number, number, number],
        second = args[1] as [number, number, number],
        last = args[args.length-1] as number;
}

foo([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], 123);
```

The code above give error:

```
Argument of type '[number[], number[], number[], 123]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[] | number[][]'.
  Type '[number[], number[], number[], 123]' is not assignable to type 'number[][]'.
    Type 'number[] | 123' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
```

P.S.
I understand it would be simpler just accept two parameters one of which is array of arrays, but I just want to know if this is possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indeed is using a spread inside the arguments type:

```
function foo(...args: [...number[][], number]) { ... }
```

Try for yourself and see:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJxwAoA6M2AcwGcAueAbTJNWQFsAjEGegXV4Bp4LDlx4BKOgDccWYAG4AsAChliQkXoBGQQCZBAZh6DNYxUrXEtug0Ybb4e+IeOnV6qw5uCPj53etOtiZmFhr2vrY+Xv6egd7h0cFulglxMRHxAX5RaTl+SUpAA)

Comment: Unexpectedly spread inside the argument type doesn't have to be last in the list... Thank you!